# Reindexing documents in elasticsearch with proper updates

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to re-index all my documents to a new index with updated mappings and a different index settings such as number of shards.

The events are published in a Kafka topic and then consumed by a service which push that event to elastic search. So, I don't want to stop consuming the events while re-indexing.

To achieve this, I have kept `primaryIndex` (name of the old index) and `secondaryIndex` (name of the new index) in `application.properties` of a spring app. So while indexing document, application will write the events to both indices (primary and secondary) and read from primary index only. Now I will run `_reindex` API to move documents from old index to a new index. As re-indexing will last for about 4-5 days, an event may get overridden by the `_reindex` API which I want to avoid.

**How can I ensure my documents are not being overridden by `_reindex` API ?**

Once re-indexing is done, I can remove secondary index from my application properties and will replace `primaryIndex` with new index name and then reading part can also be done from the new index.

**Or is there any better approach to achieve the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct `_reindex` API to move documents to new index only when it is not present in the new index. If a document is already present in new index, that can either be a new event or an update event which you don't want to get overridden.

You can give `op_type: 'create'` in the reindex API.
For more info, please follow the link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Hope this answers your question :)